# Open specific component of React Native application if a push notification is received when the application is in background

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm using [Onesignal](http://onesignal.com) push notification service in my React Native application. How can I navigate to a specific component if a notification is received when the application is in background?

I could easily do this when the notification is opened manually, i.e. notification is received and user has tapped on the notification to open it.

I can even do this when the app is in foreground. I just add `onReceived` event listener described [here](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal#handling-notifications).

But my question is how can I automatically open the application and navigate to a particular component when a notification is received?

Comment: You cannot open application remotely. At least on iOS. Only user can open applications.

Comment: Any idea using newly introduced Headless JS? Can't we add some service in BroadcaseReceiver? I don't have the concrete idea though!

Comment: The ability to open an app automatically because of a push notification would be terrifying to me as an end user. Personally I would immediately uninstall that app. I do not believe either platform allows for this type of thing to happen.

Comment: End user experience will be totally dependant on how it is implemented. Say, you are working on voice calling app where notification having certain data in it's payload should trigger the Calling screen, I think I could make the use case clear? And the OS allows this, I've already tested this in native android. Have a look at this  for referance: [NotificationReceivedHandler](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationreceivedhandler-)